# Linux shell script to pad numbers after an underscore in all file names

Tags: linux, bash, shell, batch-rename

We have a folder containing several files which have a naming sequence similar to the following:

```
000067_1.JPG
000078_20.JPG
000089_300.JPG
```

We're looking to pad the numbers only which follow the "_" of the filename, with results as follows:

```
000067_001.JPG
000078_020.JPG
000089_300.JPG
```

Being so distantly far from being an expert, I'm seeking assistance from the community in order to accomplish the objective.  The assistance and guidance is much appreciated.

We've yet to find a solution on the forum which is contingent on the positioning of numbers in relation to underscore character.

Comment: please update the question to show your (coding) efforts along with the (wrong) results generated by your code

Comment: `for i in *JPG; do new=$(echo $i| awk -F"[_.]" '{a=sprintf("%03d",$2); printf "%s_%s.%s\n",$1,a,$3}');echo mv $i $new  ;done` ... if the output looks right remove the `echo` in that's before the `mv`.

Comment: Do you know in advance, that there will allways be exactly 3 digits after the underscore, or does the number of digits vary dependent on what files you have in the directory?